# Can I set IntelliJ to auto indent the code body?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, indentation

Question 1: Can IntelliJ be set to indent the code body automatically upon making a new line?

Here is an example of what I mean:

I have this method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hi there.");
        }
```

Upon hitting the return key after typing the expression, I get this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hi there.");
        // the new line aligns itself with the braces.
        }
```

I would like it to do this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hi there.");
            // the new line aligns itself with the preceding line
        }
```

I haven't been able to locate an option anywhere under Settings that would make this the default behavior. Does it exist and am I missing it or am I looking for a unicorn?

Question 2: Is there an option to have the code body indented by default? If so, where can it be found?

Example:

Upon using the "Reformat Code..." command, I get this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        System.out.println("Hi there.");
        // the code body is realigned with the braces
        }
```

Is it possible to set IntelliJ to do this, and if so, where can I find that option?:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hi there.");
            // the code body is indented from the braces
        }
```

That is another thing I cannot seem to find in the Settings options.

Any help would be great. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `Next line, each shifted` option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**IntelliJ IDEA 15**

File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Braces placement > In method declaration > **Next line, each shifted**

[image: Next line each shifted]